# Foreign key constraint error when deleting record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get a foreign key contraint error as it states:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_5b5ddfd518" on table "posts"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(950961012) is still referenced from table "posts".
```

So my Post table is referencing a User table entry, but when the User gets deleted I dont want the Posts of the user being deleted as well. So what happens:  there is still a reference to a User who doesnt exist.

I want that relation to break when the User is deleted and keep the Post of the User maybe by making the user reference nil

Here is an exceprt of my **schema.rb**

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "category"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category"], name: "index_posts_on_category"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_posts_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "slug"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated", default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_users_on_name", unique: true
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_users_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

**user.rb**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :posts
  ...
```

**post.rb**:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy` to properly purge them? I think the default is nullify, which might not be good enough.

Comment: but doesnt this destroys all the posts of the user?

Comment: @tadman OP stated he _want that relation to break when the User is deleted and keep the Post of the User_. --- Suggestion for OP: You could use `dependent: :nullify`, if you allowed this column to have NULL values, obviously, and don't mind having Post without a clear User author.

Comment: @MrYoshiji That's true, but foreign keys say "don't break this link" so breaking the link is a contradiction. I'd suggest never deleting users, instead just flag them as deleted and pretend they're deleted with scopes.

Comment: yes thanks tadman said its by default nullify, but it isn't. This is what I was asking for the error is gone thanks. You can answer and I will amrk it as the right one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid deleting the records by switching the dependent link type:

```
has_many :posts, dependent: :nullify
```

Which flips the column to `NULL` and breaks the link. This also erases any information as to who created those posts.

As a note, in systems I design it's often important to retain information on deleted users, so it's often the case that they're not actually deleted, just flagged as deleted and made invisible by use of scopes and other tests. You can also cascade the deletion of the user into the same soft deletion of their posts.

Check your legal requirements for retention of information before arbitrarily deleting records. You may need to retain these for a period of time, in which case a `deleted_at` field can help. If that's older than *N* days, where that's the legal minimum you must retain them, you can safely purge the records.

Comment: thanks for the informations. Its just a homework Im working on but this is a nice strategy for real world applications.

Comment: I mention that because one of the first requests as a developer you usually get is in the form of "So I accidentally deleted..."